# Change cart item prices based on specific product attribute value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy, price

I am trying to change product price in cart using the following function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10);
function add_custom_price( $cart_obj ) {
    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        $item_data = $value['data'];
        $price0 = $item_data->get_attributes('per_one_price');
        $price  = (int) $price0;
        $value['data']->set_price( $num_int );
    }
}
```

But for any number I set as product attribute value for `per_one_price` attribute I get the number 1 in cart price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update** - There is 2 little mistakes:
>
> - Replace `get_attributes()` by `get_attribute()` *(singular)*.
> - Replace `'per_one_price'` by `'Per one price'` *(or `'per-one-price'` as blank spaces **are replaced by dashes**)*

So instead try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_item_price', 20, 1 );
function set_custom_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // get attibute value
        $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_attribute('per-one-price');

        if( ! empty( $new_price ) ){
            // Set the new price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

---

Create **"Per one price"** product attribute:

[image]

The product price setting view:

[image]

The product attribute set in the product with its value:

[image]

The cart page view with this product:

[image]